# How to open "save to android pay" url from android app?

Tags: java, android, android-pay

Now I'm in the following situation: our server sends ready-for-use JWT hash for current user card, but there are seems to no way to open "save to android pay" url from android app button: there are only web applications integration tutorial: https://developers.google.com/save-to-android-pay/reference/s2w-reference
So, I have to some way render this html: `<g:savetoandroidpay jwt="JWT" onsuccess="successHandler" onfailure="failureHandler" />` into button and handle javascript callbacks from Java.
Or, maybe, there are some another way?

Comment: Is it suitable for credit cards?

Comment: Yes, it's suitable. See answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43950443/how-to-open-save-to-android-pay-url-from-android-app/44391396#44391396

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Uri androidPayUri = Uri.parse("https://www.android.com/payapp/savetoandroidpay/" + jwt);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, androidPayUri);
```

...

Here you can find an example JWT to test:

https://developers.google.com/save-to-android-pay/reference/s2w-reference

Answer (score 0):

I found the "email link" way to do this, it can be used for Android app too:

```
addToAndroidPay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.android.com/payapp/savetoandroidpay/" + token));
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
```